# Applying Size() function in groupby along with the aggregate parameter - Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, automation, pandas-groupby

i want to get the number of instances when using groupby function along with the agg parameter

```
Name    Country  X_Id   Value
Rahul   1          2      100
Rahul   1          2       50
Matthew 2          3      100
Matthew 1          1       25


Name    Country  X_Id    Value  Instances  
Rahul   1          2       50     2
Matthew 2          3      100     1
Matthew 1          1       25     1
```

I used the `df.groupby(['SiteId', 'SubUnitId', 'CatId']).agg('mean').size()` but it did not work

Comment: Is input data correct? Not swapped `2` with `3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregation:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Country', 'X_Id']).agg(Value = ('Value', 'mean'),
                                            Instances = ('Value', 'size'))
```

Comment: while the code function runs fine for one column.. what if i have to apply agg funct for two columns  @jezrael

Comment: @Harishreddy - then add new values like `Instances = ('Value', 'size')` means `Instances` is new colum name, `Value` is processing column, `size` is aggregation function.

Comment: So if need `col3` to `col4` with `sum` use `col4 = ('col3','sum')`